# Perl order of execution of asterisk callback?

Tags: perl, asterisk, asteriskami

I have a code as follow:

```
 1  sub do_leave {
 2
 3    my ($asterisk, $event) = @_;
 4    my $join_id;
 5    my $id = $astman->send_action({ Action    => 'Getvar',
 6                                    Variable  => 'join_id',
 7                                    Channel   => $event->{'Channel'},
 8                                  }, \&get_value, undef, \$join_id);
 9
10    sleep(2);
11    say "join_id is: $join_id";
12
13    my $sql = "UPDATE conference_log SET duration=(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT start_conf), NOW())), end_conf=(NOW()) WHERE id=?";
14    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
15    $sth->execute($join_id);
16  }
17
18  sub get_value {
19    my ($ast, $resp, $ref_join_id) = @_;
20    for my $key (keys %$resp) {
21      if ($key eq "PARSED") {
22        $$ref_join_id = $resp->{$key}{"Value"};
23      }
24    }
25  }
```

I'm using [Asterisk::AMI](http://search.cpan.org/~greenbean/Asterisk-AMI/lib/Asterisk/AMI.pm) module for getting information from asterisk AMI.
the `do_leave` sub is called whenever someone leaves the conference. My question is `get_value` callback executed after all statements in `do_leave`.
How can i make `get_value` callback executed before line 10. Variable `\$join_id` in `send_action` is third argument to the callback. I need `$join_id` variable before sql statements.

Comment: is `send_id` guaranteed to call the `get_value` callback? So you just want to make sure that the callback has executed before you update the DB? In this case, I'll have a solution using *futures* ready for you in a moment.

Comment: @amon yes send_action will execute `get_value` callback but after DB update which also does nothing since `$sth->execute($join_id);` needs `join_id` before gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with Asterisk::AMI, but I assume that the reason the send_action method takes a callback method is that the result comes back asynchronously. You can't guarantee how long that will take.

A quick and easy solution is to place the database update inside the callback function like this:

```
sub do_leave {

  my ($asterisk, $event) = @_;
  my $get_value = sub {
    my ($ast, $resp, $ref_join_id) = @_;
    for my $key (keys %$resp) {
        if ($key eq "PARSED") {
            my $ref_join_id = $resp->{$key}{"Value"};
            my $sql = "UPDATE conference_log SET duration=(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT start_conf), NOW())), end_conf=(NOW()) WHERE id=?";
            my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute($join_id);
        }
    }
  };

  my $id = $astman->send_action({ Action    => 'Getvar',
                                  Variable  => 'join_id',
                                  Channel   => $event->{'Channel'},
                                }, $get_value);

}
```

Notice that I have used an anonymous sub, assigned to a variable, which would allow you to share variables between the outer do_leave sub and the callback sub (this is called a closure). However in this case it is probably not needed since there are no shared variables.

Comment: Thanks. I really wasn't aware of putting DB update inside of callback function.

Answer (score 2):

For minimal changes to your script,

```
sub do_leave {

  my ($asterisk, $event) = @_;
  my $join_id;

  my $sub = sub {
    get_value(@_);
    say "join_id is: $join_id";

    my $sql = "UPDATE conference_log SET duration=(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT start_conf), NOW())), end_conf=(NOW()) WHERE id=?";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($join_id);
  };
  my $id = $astman->send_action({ Action    => 'Getvar',
                                  Variable  => 'join_id',
                                  Channel   => $event->{'Channel'},
                                }, $sub, undef, \$join_id);
  # sleep(2);
}
```